# Spring MVC submit via javascript (without button) to the correct handler

Tags: javascript, spring, model-view-controller, form-submit

I have this Controller :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/path/*")
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String welcomeHandler(final Model model) {
        // SOME CODE...
    }

    @RequestMapping(params = "reloadPage", value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String reloadPageHandler(final Model model) {
        // SOME CODE...
    }

    @RequestMapping(params = "search", value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processSubmit(final BindingResult result...)
        // SOME CODE...
    }
}
```

and this jsp :

```
<form:form id="SearchFormController" method="post" modelAttribute="SearchFormBean">
    <form:select path="searchCriteria.departmentId">
        <form:options items="${addressDepartmentList}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name" />
    </form:select>

    <p>
        <button type="submit" name="reloadPage">Reload the page</button>
    </p>

    <form:select path="searchCriteria.cityId">
        <form:options items="${addressCityList}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name" />
    </form:select>

    <p>
        <button type="submit" name="search">Submit</button>
    </p>
</form:form>
```

This code works perfectly fine, when I click on the "Reload the page" button, the reloadPageHandler is called.

Now what I want to achieve, is to remove this button and put an onchange event on my jsp like this :

```
<form:select path="searchCriteria.departmentId" onchange="submit()">
    <form:options items="${addressDepartmentList}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name" />
</form:select>
```

The problem here is that when the form is submitted, it's the "processSubmit" handler that's called. But I have to call the "reloadPageHandler".

Any idea on how to do this ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the reloadPage-parameter is missing. (The former button's name.)

If you put a hidden field with this name into the form, it should work:

```
<form:form id="SearchFormController" method="post" modelAttribute="SearchFormBean">
    <input type="hidden" name="reloadPage" value=""/>

    <form:select path="searchCriteria.departmentId" onchange="submit()">
        <form:options items="${addressDepartmentList}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name" />
    </form:select>

</form:form>
```

But the problem with this code is still that always the processSubmit-Handler will be called. So a solution could be to change the controller that the reloadPageHandler is only called if reload=true. Then change the onchange to "this.form.reloadPage.value='true';submit()"

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer :) Unfortunately, it doesn't work, if I place the hidden field inside the form:select tag, the select list is not rendered :(

Comment: Sorry, I have made some stupid mistakes :( I have just corrected the answer. Let me know if is still won't work.

Comment: Now it works fine except for the second submit button : <button type="submit" name="search">Submit</button>. I guess I have to replace it as well by a javascript function ? I will try the hints you gave me to see if I can make it work.

Comment: Have you changed the controller that the reloadPageHandler is called only if "reloadPage=true"?

@RequestMapping(params = "reloadPage=true", ...

Comment: I've just changed it. Now when I try to submit via javascript I have the following error : HTTP 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported

Comment: Hm, that sounds strange. It should work, if the RequestMapping looks like this:

@RequestMapping(params = "reloadPage=true", value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String reloadPageHandler(final Model model) {
...

It's a pity i could not help you better :( I hope you'll get it running..

Comment: Yes it looks exactly like that... I keep searching. You answers are quite useful though as I learnt some things :)

Comment: OK finally you were right ! I've just restarted tomcat and now your solution is working perflectly fine ! I don't know what it didn't work in a first place (I restarted the server too that time) but now everything's ok ! Thanks a lot !! :)